# For finite $A$: $f$ injective implies $f$ surjective

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I am trying to prove:

> If $A$ is a finite set, then any injective map $f : A \to A$ is also surjective.

Here is my attempt.

> If $A = \emptyset$, then the empty function $f: A \to A$ is vacuously bijective, so suppose $A \neq \emptyset$. Let $f: A \to A$ be an injection. As $A$ is finite, there are exactly $|A|^{|A|}$ functions $A \to A$, so there exists $m > 1$ such that $f^m = f$. Fix $a \in A$, so $f^m (a) = f(a)$. By left cancellation, we have $f^{m-1} (a) = a$. That is, $f\left(f^{m-2} (a)\right) = a$; by the definition of composition, $f^{m-2} (a) \in A$ (if $m = 2$, then we define $f^0$ to be the identity function) so $f$ is surjective, as desired.

How does this look? Do I need to separate the $m=2$ case, or does the way I've handled it work?

Comment: The pigeon-hole principle would only tell you that there are $n\neq m$ such that $f^n = f^m$. The rest works fine (even in the case $m=2$).

Comment: So the assertion that there is $m > 1$ is not correct? My idea was that if I keep composing with $f$, I'll get another function $A \to A$, and eventually I'll run out of those, so there has to be some $m$ that recovers the same function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's almost correct. It seems like you cannot directly deduce that there exist $m$ such that $f^m=f$; indeed, it's not clear to me what kind of argument you are applying.

But surely you can say that among the infinite series $f, f^2, f^3, \ldots, f^m, \ldots$ there exist two of them that are equal because of the pidgeonhole principle. Is this what you meant? In this case you get that there exist $a < b$ such that $f^a = f^b$, and by (iterated) cancellation you get $f^{b-a}(x) = x$.

The rest of the proof is correct.

Comment: The idea I had is that if I keep composing with $f$, I'll get another function $A \to A$, but there are only finitely many of those, so eventually I have to recover the original function $f$ (because, if not, there are infinitely many powers of $f$, which implies $A$ is infinite).

Comment: @JeremyS, if you keep composing with $f$, of course you will only get finitely many functions $A\to A$, but it does not mean you will get $f$ again.

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you.

Comment: The last thing I'm not completely sure on: from the above work, we get $f^{b-a} (x) = x$ where $b - a \neq 0$. How from this can I deduce that $f(y) = x$ for some $y$, without knowing the value of $b-a$ and therefore how many compositions I need to unwind?

Comment: Imagine the pigeonhole principle is a magic box. You go there with your function $f$ and you ask for such $a, b$; you don't know which $a, b$ before you ask. After a while of thought, it gives you such $a, b$ (say, for example, 3 and 7). Now you go home and you are happy, because you know exactly the value of $b-a$! Hope it's clear :)